# How to get IPv4, IPv6, Network IP and Mac address of visitors in ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ip, asp.net-core-mvc

How to get IPv4, IPv6, Network IP and Mac address of visitors in ASP.NET CORE?

I already used the code below but getting only `:::1` value.

```
var remoteIpAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Answer (score -3):

**`:::1`** is for localhost address. You are getting it right. Instead you can use javascript code for that. Below is the code for that :

```
    var myIP;
    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] }), noop = function () { };
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function (ice) {  //listen for candidate events
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate) return;
        myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];
        console.log('my IP: ', myIP);
        $('#IpAddress').val(myIP);
        pc.onicecandidate = noop;
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the help but , i need to capture the IPv4, IPv6, Network IP and Mac address of visitors in asp.net core. Kindly can you help me in this?

Comment: The question is to get it through .NET Core and you just said "instead you can use JS"